# Why does this while loop "hang"?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have this while loop in a program I am writing.  It acquires transaction data from a website and generates a response.  It runs as long as there are no transactions from the site, but when it acquires a result from the site, it responds then stops continuing the loop.  Any input is appreciated.

```
while True:
    atran = getatran()
    ntid = getntid()
    if (ntid != otid and ntid != "-1"):
        otid = ntid
        tlidfile = open('last_transaction_id.txt', 'w')
        tlidfile.write(str(otid))
        tlidfile.close()
        for x in range(len(atran['transactions'])) :
            amount = atran['transactions'][x-1]['amount']
            currency = atran['transactions'][x-1]['currency']
            note = atran['transactions'][x-1]['note']
            if note[:14] == "Transfer from:":
                sender = note[15:]
                if (sender == "satoshi4free") or (sender == "rabbit") or (sender == "mehbot") or (currency != 17): pass
                else: flip(currency,amount,sender)
    print "New: " + str(ntid)
    print "Old: " + str(otid)
    sleep(1)
```

The 'print "New: "' and 'print "Old: "' statements were added as a trouble shooting measure. Coincidentally, when ntid != "-1" is when the loop stops.  However, the loop completes at least through the 'print "Old: "' statement, and I assume, the 'sleep' statement.

I have a similar function that acquires messages and responds to them. It works perfectly. It is as follows:

```
while(condition == True):
    amsg = getamsg()
    nid = getnid()
    if (nid != oid and nid != "-1"):
        oid = nid
        try:
            for x in range(len(amsg['message_list'])) :
                msg = amsg['message_list'][x-1]['msg']
                pm = amsg['message_list'][x-1]['me']
                sender = amsg['message_list'][x-1]['by']
                if (msg.lower() == 'ping'):
                    condition = pong()
                    sleep(1)
                if (msg.lower() == 'help'):
                    condition = helper()
                    sleep(1)
                if (msg.lower() == 'luckydoge'):
                    condition = lucky()
                    sleep(1)                       
        except (TypeError,KeyError):
            pass
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it kind of sounds like it is actually hanging in `getatran()` or `getntid()`.  Maybe add some print statements around those and see?

Comment: Your description of the problem is a little vague. What do you mean by "the loop stops"? Does the loop exit? As there are no break statements the "while True" loop should run forever as long as none of the functions called within the loop force a system.exit or other shenanigans.

Comment: Agree with @woot. Put `print "Before getatran"`, `print "Before getntid"`, and `print "After getntid"1` statements into the code.

Comment: The loop does not exit... it hangs...

Comment: added the print statements requested... I added 'print "test" before "atran = getatran()", added "print atran" after "atran = getatran()" added "print ntid" after "ntid = getntid()"...

Comment: results are: starting main transactor
otid: 1161800
test

Connecting to ...
1161801
New: 1161801
Old: 1161801
True
test

Comment: Ok, so `getatran()` is blocking or hanging.  Is this one of your functions?  You'll need to dig inside, but most likely it is waiting on some connection, and there is no timeout set on it (or a very long one) while it waits.

Comment: I added print statements before every line in the loop and in getatran. getatran was looping because of a bit of troubleshooting code I forgot to remove!!  Now I feel chagrined!  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: how is the while loop exiting here? the "nid != "-1" condition only evaluates the if statement, I am not sure if it applies for breaking the loop..

Comment: @durga this loop runs in a daemon thread. On shutdown the main thread checks that nid == "-1" before exiting.  Otherwise, the loop is infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to title your question:

> Why does my while loop "hang"?

You obviously have something that's hanging, and to deduce what it is, you need to add `print` on each line (easiest), or more difficult (unless you have an IDE that helps you): step through it with a debugger, or run it through a profiler.

I think that answers the question as directly as it can, there's not enough information to provide you with a more specific deduction.

Comment: I changed the 'print "test"' statement to "print 'begin while loop'" which seems to be where the loop hangs...